# Why does Google Reverse Geocoding return ZERO_RESULTS on some GPS coordinates?

Tags: php, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I'm using Reverse Geocoding service and I get "ZERO_RESULTS".
In my PHP scripts I created the following function:

```
public static function getJsonData($lat, $lng, $apikey) {
    $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$lat.",".$lng."&language=en-EN&key=". $apikey;

    $json = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, self::_createContext());

    return $json;
}
```

Here is a list of some of GPS coordinates for which I get no results:

- [Example 1](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=31.71255,35.22438&language=en-EN)
- [Example 2](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.0960717,74.7630145&language=en-EN)
- [Example 3](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=23.6619453,-15.9696937&language=en-EN)
- [Example 4](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=31.9140945,35.022043&language=en-EN)
- [Example 5](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.1903376,33.3525061&language=en-EN)

I also tried to submit the coordinates on this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse, but I get the following alert error:

**Geocoder failed due to: ZERO_RESULTS**.

If I try to search for the same coordinates on Google Maps, it works, it find the related places on the map, with no troubles:

- [Example 1](https://www.google.com/maps/place/31%C2%B042'45.2%22N+35%C2%B013'27.8%22E/@31.7125545,35.2221913,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d31.71255!4d35.22438)
- [Example 2](https://www.google.com/maps/place/34%C2%B005'45.9%22N+74%C2%B045'46.9%22E/@34.0960761,74.7608258,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d34.0960717!4d74.7630145)
- [Example 3](https://www.google.com/maps/place/23%C2%B039'43.0%22N+15%C2%B058'10.9%22W/@23.6619502,-15.9718824,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d23.6619453!4d-15.9696937)
- [Example 4](https://www.google.com/maps/place/31%C2%B054'50.7%22N+35%C2%B001'19.4%22E/@31.914099,35.0198543,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d31.9140945!4d35.022043)
- [Example 5](https://www.google.com/maps/place/35%C2%B011'25.2%22N+33%C2%B021'09.0%22E/@35.190342,33.3503174,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d35.1903376!4d33.3525061)

So, why Reverse Geocoding fails?

---

**EDIT:**

I used the same coordinates with MapQuest reverse geocoding API and it works. I get the following countries:

- Palestine
- India
- Morocco
- Israel
- Cyprus

Why does MapQuest API work with disputed areas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the first coordinate in your examples in geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D31.71255%252C35.22438

The 31.71255,35.22438 is located in the West Bank area. West Bank is the disputed area and this is a known issue for Google reverse geocoder. All coordinates in disputed areas return ZERO_RESULTS.

There is a bug for this in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826813

Feel free to star the bug to add your vote and hopefully Google will solve it soon.

- Example 2 - Jammu and Kashmir
- Example 3 - Western Sahara
- Example 4 - West Bank
- Example 5 - North Cyprus

All these territories are disputed areas:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes

#### Update

Good news. As of January 2019 Google resolved an issue with ZERO_RESULTS in disputed areas.

You can see that now they return results, but country name doesn't appear in responses. This aligns with approach that they had in forward geocoder. Disputed areas don't have country names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see that you posted a new comment in that issue linking this SO question. Am I right? Anyway, can you tell me why MapQuest reverse geocoding service returns the places? I have updated my question.

Comment: Not sure about MapQuest, the Google politics is do not return the country name for disputed areas. At least in forward geocoding it works this way. You can get street number, street name, locality name, but not the country name.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Cyprus in Google Maps, it looks like they do not have data in this region, hence the lack of response.

I would look into other rgeo services if you need this area. Perhaps look into Skyhook, Baidu, or Mapquest.